# Which Android audio player supports SMB and album artwork in separate files?

Tags: android, media-player, smb

I'm looking for an Android audio player app supporting SMB.
It should also be able to display album artwork stored as cover.jpg or back.jpg in the same folder as the audio files.

Answer (score 1):

**Samba Network Music Player** fits both of your needs (SMB & Album cover), and a bit more (like play from local device & SD card).
I'm only unsure of cover file naming convention.

You can get it from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.threecats.sambaplayer)

It contains some ads, but nothing disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

JetAudio definitely supports SMB; From the [app store page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jetappfactory.jetaudio&hl=en_GB&gl=US):

> It can stream music from shared folders on local home network or
> WebDAV servers. It works with shared folders from Windows, USB drive
> attached to router, Network drives (NAS) or WebDAV servers.

Unsure whether it supports jpg album art, but there's a free version to test with.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).